# Bernoulli-like generating function

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, bernoulli-numbers, formal-power-series, taylor-expansion

What are the coefficients of the series for:
$$\frac x{e^x+1}$$
It looks similar to the Bernoulli generating function, but the $+$ sign is throwing me off.

> I already found the series for its inverse. If $x=\frac y{e^y+1}$, then:
>   $$y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\binom nkk^{n-1}\right)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$
>   —that is, that finite series in the middle is the $n$th coefficient of the exponential generating function. (Wolfram Alpha can't reduce it to a simpler form.) (If you're bored later today, by the way, it's a nice challenge to derive that.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are [Genocchi numbers](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GenocchiNumber.html), when you multiply by 2. In particular even Genocchi numbers are related to Bernoulli numbers:

$$G_{2k}=2(1-2^{2k})B_{2k}.$$

Comment: Thank you! That means that$$\frac x{e^x+1}=\frac x{e^x-1}-\frac{2x}{e^{2x}-1}$$(which is easily checked). That's a very interesting formula.

Comment: @columbus8myhw: Neat observation. You can probably get a more holistic explanation from the fact that $\eta(s)=(1-2^{1-s})\zeta(s)$, the alternating zeta function vs the Riemann zeta function. Indeed, $\zeta(s)\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u-1}du$ and $\eta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_0^\infty \frac{u^{s-1}}{e^u+1}du$, but the proof for the identity is much simpler from the series representation of $\zeta(s)$ and $\eta(s)$.

Comment: Ah, that's a nice connection! I wonder if that has any relation to the inverse function series I found.